# Bernoulli process with different types of successes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am considering a situation in which a player engages in a lottery with $J$ rounds. In each round, with probability $p$, she wins a prize, and with probability $1-p$ she wins no prize. At the start, there are $N$ prizes with $K$ good prizes and $N-K$ bad prizes (prizes are not replaced). I'm looking for an expression that gives the probability of winning exactly $k$ good prizes in $J$ rounds. I believe that the overall number of prizes would be binomially distributed, and that for $p=1$, the probability of getting $k$ good prizes in $j$ draws would be given by the hypergeometric distribution. But I'm having trouble reasoning about two processes layered on top of one another. Can anyone give a hint as to how I should proceed? Thanks in advance and sorry if this could be notated in a better way.

My initial attempt at reasoning:

Let $x$ be the total number of prizes won in $J$ rounds. In order to win $k$ good prizes, we need to win at least $x=k$ prizes overall and can win at most $J$ prizes. For each number of prizes that we win, there is some probability of winning $k$ good prizes. So my best attempt would be to say we sum Pr(winning $x$ prizes)$\cdot$Pr($k$ good prizes | $x$) over all $k \leq x \leq J$. Which I suppose would give
$$f(k; x,J,N,K,p)=\sum_{x=k}^J \Bigl[\binom{J}{x}p^x(1-p)^{J-x}\Bigr]\cdot\Bigl[\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{x-k}}{\binom{N}{x}}\Bigr]$$

where $N$ is the total number of prizes to start, $K$ is the number of good prizes to start, and $p$ is the probability of winning a prize in each round.

Comment: Great Question! But please add your attempts so that we could correct or build upon it. Also, I suggest you add where you got the problem from.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Thanks — I have edited to show my initial attempt. I got the problem from thinking about the decision theory of some digital goods like loot boxes in video games.

Comment: You are really close to the actually solution. This type of distribution is call "Hypergeometric" instead of binomial or bernoulli. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: @Bayesian Thanks very much. I thought that this quantity would reduce to the hypergeometric only if you were guaranteed to "win a prize" every time ($p=1$). But that if winning a prize in each round is governed by a Bernoulli process, it would be different. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.